# Finding words that are close together with PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, full-text-search, innodb

Is there a way to find words that often appear close together with PostgreSQL. I know MySQL supports this with **InnoDB** tables when using **proximity search**.

Example:

```
select quote as "Too Far Apart" 
from quotes
where match(quote) against ('"early wise" @20' in boolean mode);
```

Comment: **[Similarities and distance between strings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/fuzzystrmatch.html)**

Comment: I think that this only work for finding similar words, not words that appear close together

Answer (score 0):

`ts_rank_cd` provides a different value depending on how far apart the terms are.

```
select
    ts_rank_cd( 
        to_tsvector('simple', 'the quick brown fox'), 
        plainto_tsquery('simple', 'the fox') 
    ) first,
    ts_rank_cd( 
        to_tsvector('simple', 'the quick brown fox'), 
        plainto_tsquery('simple', 'quick brown') 
    ) second;
```

Output:

```
first       second
0.0333333   0.1
```

`0.1 / ts_rank_cd` seems to give the actual distance between words

Comment: Thanks. This actually looks like a good solution. I'll test it a bit to be sure.